# jquery onclick change image not working, Correct Code i think

Tags: onclick, jscript

I have a really simple onclick event to change the image of an image in a div, but for whatever reason i keep getting an undefined back instead of the image source.

iv tried every which way around and still had no luck.

can anyone see from the code below where i am going wrong please.

thank you.

```
$messageid=$row['id'];

<div class='Mimage3'>

        <input type='file' class='INimage' id='input3{$messageid}' onClick='showFiles(this , \"image3{$messageid}\" ,  \"input3{$messageid}\"   , {$messageid});' accept='image/*' > 

        <label for='input3' class='LMimage'>
        <img id='image3{$messageid}' class='vimage' src='{$image3}'></img>
      </label>

    </div>


<script>
function showFiles(thisID, imageID , inputID , messageID ) {


        var imageid=imageID;                                                        //passed imageID --onclick   \"image3\"+{$messageid}
        var messageid=messageID;                                                    //passed messageID --onclick {$messageid} 
        var ebm=document.getElementById('editSeller'+messageid+'');                 //passed messageID --onclick {$messageid}
        var inputID=inputID;                                                        //passed inputID  --onclick   \"input3\"+{$messageid} 
        var input=thisID;                                                           //passed thisID    --onclick   this 

        console.log('imageid='+imageid);  // shows the id correctly


      // attempt 1 var imagesrc = $(imageid 'img').attr('src');    

     // attempt 2 var imagesrc = $('#'+imageid 'img').attr('src');  

    // attempt 3 var imagesrc = ($imageid).find('img').attr('src'));    

   // attempt 4 var imagesrc = $(imageid).attr('src');  

  // attempt 5 var imagesrc = $(imageid).find('img').attr('src');   

 // attempt 6 var imagesrc = $('#'+imageid).find('img').attr('src');     


 console.log(imagesrc);  // but this returns undefined???



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

var imagesrc = $('#' + imageid).attr('src');

oops...
forget to try that 1..